# Does the Windows version of MAGMA have a memory limit?

Tags: math-software, computational-algebra, magma-cas

Sorry if this isn't the best place to ask support type MAGMA questions, but I haven't found a single forum or anything for MAGMA users to talk.

I have access to a copy of MAGMA which is running on a server at my school (the operating system is "Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise").  I've been told the server has 16GB of memory and there's no limit to how much a single user can use (I'm apparently usually the only person on this server).  But for some reason I keep getting system errors from MAGMA any time it tries to request more than ~1400MB of memory.

Does anyone know how I can determine if this is an error in the way the server is set up or if this is an inherent limitation of MAGMA?

Comment: Probably okay to post here, but there is also http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewforum.php?f=2

Comment: Computer algebra software questions are welcomed here, so it is a fine place to post about MAGMA.

Comment: @mathguy: Apparently there are two MAGMA's, the one I am speaking of is different than the one you've linked to: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/

Comment: @Jim Whoops, i don't know about either of them =P sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted MAGMA and for the record:

Windows apparently did something weird with their definition of a "long" integer in the 64bit operating system, so MAGMA on Windows is only supported in 32bit.  The maximum memory MAGMA can draw as a 32bit application is 1.3GB.  As this is a system limit and not an internal limit `GetMemoryLimit()` will still return $0$.

The only solution is to run MAGMA in 64bit on either OSX or Linux.

Answer (score 5):

MAGMA's memory limit is stored under the environmental variable MAGMA_MEMORY_LIMIT.  You can view the value of this variable with `GetMemoryLimit()`, and you can set its value with `SetMemoryLimit(n)`.  If you want to remove the memory limit, use `SetMemoryLimit(0)`.  Of course, you will still be constrained by the memory limits of your system.

Note that in the student version of MAGMA, there is a soft memory limit of 150MB which you cannot modify.

Comment: `GetMemoryLimit()` returns 0 and generally the error messages say that the current session is ~1200MB when failure occurs.  So I guess this means it's some sort of system error on the server.  But if there's 16GB of memory available I don't know why this would be.