# Workaround for Windows Magma Memory Limit

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766594/does-the-windows-version-of-magma-have-a-memory-limit) which said that Magma for Windows has a strict memory limit of 1.3 GB as a consequence of something weird with long ints.

Is there any known workaround for this **on a Windows machine**? Would running in an Ubuntu subsystem or a virtual machine solve the problem, even though such subsystems would still be overlaid onto Windows? Should I expect a large performance hit?

Comment: Yes, installing a Linux version in Ubuntu or a virtual machine would solve this. Then you would not be running the Windows version. This is actually answered in the linked question ("The only solution is to run MAGMA in 64bit on either OSX or Linux.")

Comment: Also a workaround of some kind: if this calculation is possible in GAP, its 32-bit Windows version can claim a bit more memory, and we also provide an experimental 64-bit version, see http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/